# Running Rails commands in ConEmu using {bash::mintty} not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, git-bash, conemu, mintty

Every time I run a Rails command such as `rails -v` in ConEmu using the *{bash::mintty}* terminal, I get the following error: `unknown mingwarch "msys" (RuntimeError)`.

However, `ruby -v` works perfectly fine. In every other terminal, such as *{cmd}* and *{PowerShell}* (using ConEmu), or in the **Git Bash** app, I can run `rails -v` without any problem. I don't know where the error comes from.

Here is the full trace:

```
$ rails -v
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:36:in `initialize': unknown mingwarch "msys" (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:17:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:17:in `msys2_installation'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:27:in `enable_dll_search_paths'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:1427:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:1427:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

I am using Windows 11, Rails 7.0.2.2, ConEmu 210912, Bash version 4.4.23(2) and Git for Windows 2.35.1.windows.2 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In Cmder's settings. Go to *Startup* → *Tasks* and click on *Add/Refresh default tasks*, and on the dialog box, click *Refresh default tasks*.

Then, in the *Startup* section (the parent one, neither the *Tasks* section, nor *Environment*), select the *Specified named task* to `{Bash::Git bash}`. And now everything works perfectly fine!

This [link](https://dev.to/shrihankp/make-your-terminal-look-swag-with-msys2-and-zsh-32b7) helped me.